# How do I make a part of a border rounded in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I already know how to make a rounded border for an object in HTML. But how do I round only one or two corners?

Comment: did you google before you asked? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can do this:

```
#example1 {
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

or

```
#example2 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Rounder corners can be created independently using the four individual border-*-radius properties (border-bottom-left-radius, border-top-left-radius, etc.) or for all four corners simultaneously using the border-radius shorthand property.

**The Sintax**

```
border-*-*-radius: [ <length> | <%> ] [ <length> | <%> ]?
```

**Example:**

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10% 5%;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a different `border-radius` to each corner (or just what you need). Example:

```
div{
    background-color: blue;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/npt8yyxw/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-radius property like this:

```
border-radius: 22px 30px 10px 10px; /*top-left,top-right,bottom-right,bottom-left*/
-moz-border-radius: 22px 30px 10px 10px;/*top-left,top-right,bottom-right,bottom-left*/
-webkit-border-radius: 22px 30px 10px 10px;/*top-left,top-right,bottom-right,bottom-left*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The border-radius attribute can be written with 4 values. Starting at the top left moving clock-wise.

```
.some-class {
  border-radius: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#rounded {
    border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px;
```

The first number (15px in this example) is the top left corner
The second number (50px in this example) is the top right corner
The third number (30px in this example) is the bottom right corner
The fourth number (5px in this example) is the bottom left corner

The higher the number, the more rounded, the lower the number the closer it is to being more square.
Just change the #rounded to match your CSS tag for your code.